# The import android.pim cannot be resolved

Tags: android

I have the following import in my android class Clock -

```
import android.pim.DateUtils;
```

But the compiler is giving me the error -

The import android.pim cannot be resolved.

I am using the Android 2.1-update1 jar.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `android.pim` package in [the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/index.html).

There is an [`android.text.format.DateUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html) class, however.